# App switches acttivity or leaves app if countdowntimer is finished and phone is sleeping

Tags: android, firebase, countdowntimer

I am using a CountDownTimer to start an intent from A to B when it's finished.

```
countDownTimer= new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

     public void onFinish() {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);

                 startActivity(intent);
                finish();
             }
            }.start();
```

everything works fine except in the case that the app is still open in the foreground and the phone is sleeping, it takes me to another activity C which is not even mentioned in activity A nor in B. knowing that the activity C is restricted for only the admin and it takes me to that activity only if the admin account was previously open on that device. If the admin account was never open with that device, it just leaves the app. In both cases, the current user id remains the same, so I prevented the first case by verifying in activity C if the current user id is equal to the id of the admin, if not I start an intent to the activity A.
But,this is really confusing and it means something is wrong with my app.
What do you think is causing this issue ? what should I check ?